# Mockito mistakenly (?) fails with TooManyActualInvocations for mutable class

Tags: mockito

The following is the test which illustrates the failure.

```
class Parameter {
    public int field;
    Parameter(int init) {
        field = init;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        return field == ((Parameter)o).field;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Parameter{field=" + field + "}";
    }
}

interface Method {
    void method(Parameter parameter);
}

@Test
public void mockitoTest() {
    Method mock = mock(Method.class, "mock");
    Parameter parameter = new Parameter(0);
    mock.method(parameter); // LINE 1
    parameter.field++;
    mock.method(parameter); // LINE 2
    then(mock).should().method(new Parameter(1)); // LINE 3
}
```

It produces the following error.

> org.mockito.exceptions.verification.TooManyActualInvocations:
>   mock.method(Parameter{field=1});
>   Wanted 1 time:
>   -> at LINE 3 
>   But was 2 times. Undesired invocation:
>   -> at LINE 2

Now, what seems to happen is that Mockito captures reference to the *parameter* at LINE 1 when *field* was 0. That *field* is then incremented to 1 in the next line and remains so until LINE 3 where verification happens. and so Mockito mistakenly thinks that there were 2 invocations while the first one was clearly `mock.method(Parameter{field=0});`

How do I instruct Mockito to properly recognize this situation?

Answer (score 0):

When no Matchers are used to check the nvokations, moquite uses equals for checking the invocatcions

As you pass in the same reference (and I guess that Parameter checks the object identity and not its values when do .equals()) there are two invocations for mockito in your line

```
 then(mock).should().method(new Parameter(1)); // LINE 3
```

So you can either create a new reference for Parameter

```
Parameter zero = new Parameter(0)
Parameter one = new Parameter(1)
```

Or you can use Matchers (e.g. [Mockito.argThat](https://static.javadoc.io/org.mockito/mockito-core/2.2.7/org/mockito/ArgumentMatchers.html#argThat(org.mockito.ArgumentMatcher)))

```
// I didn't try this out - you need hamcrest on your classpath
then(mock).should().method(Mockito.argThat(new HasPropertyWithValue("field", new IsEqual(0)))
```

Comment: 1) yes, I know that Mockito uses equals for verification; and no need to guess what Parameter does in its equals() method as for that reason I included it in the attached code snippet. 2) this is just a simplified example to illustrate the issue. Normally, the code that operates on the mock is not in the test method, but in the production code. So creating there new instances of the Parameter class just for the sake of testing framework seems like a violation of separation of concerns.

Comment: 3) And finally, using Matchers during verification on LINE 3 will not help as they would still test the state of the object as it is in that line and not as it was during the actual method invocation on LINE 1.